# <Link> wont re-render a component after Private/Public routing and redux integration

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, material-ui

Update: I uploaded a demo on codepen https://codesandbox.io/s/yjl2j4ko9

I have a Drawer from material-ui css lib (an admin control panel) with inside the AppRouter. I navigate trough sections with `<Link>` but after integrating redux and public/privare routes `<Link>` only changes the URL and not re-render the component inside the Drawer. If I refresh the page the re-render works. Here my router:

```
<Router history={history}>
<div>
      <Switch>
            <PublicRoute path="/" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/Control" component={Control} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/Persons" component={Persons} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/Graphs" component={Graphs} />

        </Switch>
  </div>
```

With my old route (without private/public paths) worked fine. 
ex:

```
    <Route path="/Controls" render={()=><Controls/>}/>
```

I've already tried pure:false in privateroute.js, what can I try? there's a way you use something like `render={()=><Controls/>}` also in public private routes?

Comment: as i wrote, i already tryed to pass {pure: false} to connect, and also withRouter

Comment: you need to provide more code then, maybe you can set up example on codesandbox?

Comment: yep, done https://codesandbox.io/s/yjl2j4ko9

Comment: but it doesn't compile.

Comment: But I have an idea. Try to put `{ pure: false }` to every possible `connect` in the app (remember it's forth argument). Just to make it's not related.

Comment: ok thanks, now i try, now on codepen is compiling

Comment: Nothing changes with {pure:false}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicated your router context in AppRouter which should be simply:

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <div>
    <PublicRoute path="/" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/Buckets" component={BucketsPage} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/Payments" component={PaymentsPage} />
  </div>
);
```

You have already configured react-router in index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,

  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

So you can remove `{ pure: false }` and other unnecessary `withRouter` hocs unless they are required.